# How to select a button with its id equals to some variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my button's text value by finding that button by its id.
i have one variable buttionid='3' and trying below code:

```
$("#slips :button[id=buttionid]").html('mytext'); // it is not working
```

however below code is working:

```
$("#slips :button[id='3']").html('mytext');
```

I need to find button with its id but id is provided by user so search could be dynamic.

Use case is:

I have one input tag form there i am fetching inputs like (3,10)

so I want to assign value as '10' to button with id='3'.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: `$("#" + buttionid).html('mytext');`

Comment: Because an id value can only be used once on a page, you don't need any of the other contextual stuff in the selector string. Just `"#" + buttonid` is all you need.

Comment: but that button is in one specific div which is slips.

Comment: That does not matter. If you use the same id more than once, things probably won't work no matter what you do in your selector string. The old "Sizzle" library would ignore everything else in the selector once it determined that the target was an id selector, and I would not be surprised if the implementation of `querySelector()` in browsers did the same thing.

Comment: ok but what if it is i want to select with class attribute which can be duplicate.

Comment: @JainKaushal Update the question with the usecase you mean.

Comment: Selecting by class is quite different than selecting by id; your question explicitly said "id".

Answer (score 0):

```
$(`#slips :button[id=${buttionid}]`).html('mytext');
```

Comment: This would work but the selector string is needlessly complicated.

Comment: Will suggest calling a function here `[id=${getButtonId()}]` which will retun string

Comment: this is not working, I also thought same solution but it is not working.

Comment: Create a fiddle so that we can help.

Comment: Please do not forget to also explain your answer: How are you solving the problem and why in this way?